# How can an anonymous class have arguments?

Tags: java, class, interface, anonymous

I'm not a java guy but I've inherited some code I need to patch up. I pulled the source into netbeans and I'm getting the error: Anonymous class implements interface; cannot have arguments.

Here's the code:

```
Executor background = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Runnable mylookupThread = new Runnable(FilePath, SearchIndex)
{
    public void run()
    { MainWindow.this.processFile(this.val$FilePath);
        Thread t = new Thread(new lookupThread(MainWindow.arrFile, true, false, this.val$SearchIndex));
        t.setName("Lookup");
        t.setPriority(10);
        t.start();
    }
};
background.execute(mylookupThread);
Executor statusThread = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Runnable myStatusThread = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    { MainWindow.this.updateStatus();
    }
};
statusThread.execute(myStatusThread);
```

The error pops up on the second line. Help?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `mylookupThread` separate class, make it's instance and pass it to `Executor`:

```
class LookupTask implements Runnable {
    private final String filePath, searchIndex;
    LookupTask(String filePath, String searchIndex) {
       this.filePath = filePath;
       this.searchIndex = searchIndex;
    }

    public void run() { ... } 
}
...
background.execute(new LookupTask(filePath, searchIndex));
```

Other way around is to make `filePath, searchIndex` final:

```
final String filePath = ...
final String searchIndex = ...
Executor background = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Runnable mylookupThread = new Runnable() {
    public void run() { MainWindow.this.processFile(filePath);
        Thread t = new Thread(new lookupThread(MainWindow.arrFile, true, false, searchIndex));
        t.setName("Lookup");
        t.setPriority(10);
        t.start();
    }
};
background.execute(mylookupThread);
```

Answer (score 1):

An anonymous class of the form new -interface- implicitly extends Object.  You have to use one of the [constructors for Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#constructor_summary).  There is only one - the no-args constructor.

Comment: Every Java class extends Object.

Comment: True, but not every class implicitly, directly extends Object.  If it was explicit e.g. `lookupThread = new Object ( FilePath , SeatchPath ) { ... }` it would be more obvious why arguments are not allowed.

Comment: Ah, but you're not creating an Object -- you're creating an instance of an anonymous class. The limitation to a no-argument constructor comes not from the Object class, but from the language definition itself. It would remain even if new constructors were added to Object tomorrow. See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.9.5.1

Comment: If I could wave my magic wand and add a public Object ( int val ) constructor to the Object class, then why couldn't I create an instance of an anonymous class like `Object obj = new Object ( 5 ) ;`  This would be what the language definition refers to as an anonymous constructor.

Comment: I am completely, utterly wrong. You're right. The link I cited myself specifies exactly the behavior you describe. +1.

Answer (score 1):

@Victor is right that you can create another class.  You can also use variables inside an anonymous class that are `final`.  Something like the following will work.

```
Executor background = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
private final FilePath filePath = ...;
private final String searchIndex = ...;
Runnable mylookupThread = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        MainWindow.this.processFile(filePath);
        Thread t = new Thread(new lookupThread(MainWindow.arrFile, true, false,
           searchIndex));
        t.setName("Lookup");
        t.setPriority(10);
        t.start();
    }
};
```

Btw.  It's a little strange to create a thread inside the `Runnable` of a thread executing in an executor.  Not sure why you wouldn't just spawn the `LookupThread` directly and remove the anonymous class altogether.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem line (as you said:)

```
Runnable mylookupThread = new Runnable(FilePath, SearchIndex) { ...
```

What's happening is that we're defining a class on-the-fly, and that class implements the `Runnable` interface. When you use this syntax, the items in the parentheses are intended as constructor arguments for the superclass. Since `Runnable` is an interface, not a class, it has no constructors at all, so there are definitely none that take arguments.

That said, whatever those are supposed to be, they're not used in the body of the anonymous class, so to a first approximation, you want to just drop what's inside the parentheses altogether.